# Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier in SQL SERVER select statement

Tags: sql-server

When I execute the query below, I get the error

> Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_IncidentDetails where IncidentId = '1822CBE-4616-4ABE-B562-D3CC925D68ED'
```

Below is my column data

[image]

Appreciate assistance

Comment: I assume `IncidentId` is a `uniqueidentifier` column. The value you've given is not a `uniqueidentifier`, as your first set of characters is one character too short. A `uniqueidentifier` is in the form xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx (notice 8 X's before the first dash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is pretty clear, that value isn't a `uniqueidentifier`.

If you check against a proper GUID (i.e. `SELECT NEWID()` -> `919053E6-7CE6-4324-9A58-A2EACA5E0F5F`) notice that the first "block" has 8 characters (`919053E6`). Yours, however, has 7 characters (`1822CBE`).

*On consideration, this is probably simply a typographical error.*